# Custom Jackson setter method for Lists of a specific generic type

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want to deserialize a data structure that has several lists containing objects of a specific subtype - i.e. several `List<? extends CustomElement>`. Each list is a different subclass of `CustomElement`. When setting these fields, I need to do some additional actions each time an element is added to the list, so I have several `addElement(CustomElement)` methods that handle this when the structure is being created with code. An example:

```
private List<CustomResourceCost> costs;
private List<CustomEffect> effects;

public void addCost(CustomResourceCost cost) {
    //other actions
    costs.add(cost);
}

public void addEffect(CustomEffect effect) {
    //other actions
    effects.add(effect);
}
```

(`CustomResourceCost` and `CustomEffect` both extend `CustomElement`)

Is there a way to make sure Jackson uses these `addX` methods, without each time adding a setter like the following? I have about 50 instances where this used, so would prefer not to repeat this over and over.

```
public void setEffects(List<CustomEffect> effects) {
    effects.clear();
    effects.forEach(e -> addEffect(e));
}
```

Note that deserializing the `List<CustomElement>` is not a problem, this happens correctly with default Jackson behaviour. Rather, I want to customize the way a *setter method* is called for this type of object (without requiring a new setter method for each instance). Is there a way to specify your own custom setter method based on the generic object type?